# a function within if else statement not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My function seem not to work and I am not sure why. It should return true or false but it doesnt. I am trying to calculate if the value is lower than 0 and if so return false, true otherwise.

```js
function tickets(peopleInLine){
    // ...
    var twentyfive = 0;
    var fifty = 0;
    var hundred = 0;
    
    
    function checkforsales() {
      if ((twentyfive < 0) || (fifty < 0) ||  (hundred < 0)) {
          return false 
      } else {
              return true
      }   
    }
       
    for (let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
      if(peopleInLine[i] === 25) {
          twentyfive = twentyfive + 25;

      } else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) {
          fifty = fifty + 50;
          twentyfive = twentyfive - 25;
          checkforsales();

      } else {
          hundred = hundred + 100;
          checkforsales();
      }
    }
}

console.log(tickets([25, 100]));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
 function tickets(peopleInLine){
    // ...
    var twentyfive = 0;
    var fifty = 0;
    var hundred = 0;


    function checkforsales() {
    if ((twentyfive < 0) || (fifty < 0) ||  (hundred < 0)) {
        return false 
    } else {
            return true
        }

    }


    for (let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
    if(peopleInLine[i] === 25) {
        twentyfive = twentyfive + 25;

    } else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) {
        fifty = fifty + 50;
        twentyfive = twentyfive - 25;

    } else {
        hundred = hundred + 100;
    }
  }

  return checkforsales();

}

console.log(tickets([25, 100]));
```

You need to return checkforsales function as below

```
 function tickets(peopleInLine){
    // ...
    var twentyfive = 0;
    var fifty = 0;
    var hundred = 0;


    function checkforsales() {
    if ((twentyfive < 0) || (fifty < 0) ||  (hundred < 0)) {
        return false 
    } else {
            return true
        }

    }


    for (let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
    if(peopleInLine[i] === 25) {
        twentyfive = twentyfive + 25;

    } else if (peopleInLine[i] === 50) {
        fifty = fifty + 50;
        twentyfive = twentyfive - 25;

    } else {
        hundred = hundred + 100;
    }
  }

  return checkforsales();

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. if possible take checkforsales() outside of For loop to avoid writing twice.